# How to make image render Elm?

Tags: html, elm

How do I make an image render within Elm view?

Here is my code:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ img [src "https://cameras.liveviewtech.com/img/LVLogo_small.png"] []
        , input [ onInput ChangeUserInput ] []
        , button [ onClick ClearText ] [ text "Clear" ]
        , button [ onClick SaveText ] [ text "Save" ]
        , div [] (List.map rowItem model.textToDisplay)
        ]
```

I'm getting the error code

**I cannot find an "img" variable:** and **I cannot find a "src" variable:**.

How do I make the image display? What am I doing wrong?

Here are my imports:

```
module Main exposing (main)    
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, h1, input, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, onInput)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, h1, input, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, onInput)
```

It seems you already know how to import the functions representing individual html elements, so to solve the issue with `img` simply add it to the list of exposed imports from `Html`. As for `src`, like all functions representing HTML attributes, this comes from `Html.Attributes`.

So simply change the above to:

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, h1, img, input, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, onInput)
import Html.Attributes exposing (src)
```